# asp.net mvc dictionary sort

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
return new MultiSelectList(dic, "Key", "Value", sel);
```

How can I sort by value in the dictionary value above? The dictionary is filled by database values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the "database values" before adding them to the dictionary, but that would not be entirely reliable.

Use LINQ - type

```
return 
    new MultiSelectList
    (
       dic.OrderBy(x => x.Value), 
       "Key", 
       "Value", 
        sel
    )
;
```